# Highcharts remove spacing on 0 value bars in group

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart that has five groups of two bars.

The first bar in each group is the target for that category e.g. Day target, Week target etc.

I have it working but I am getting spaces between bars that aren't there.

My data is:

```
0: {name:Target, color:#85D6FF, data:[0, 272.73, 4363.68, 0, 0]}
1: {name:Day, data:[{y:0, color:#63D654}]}
2: {name:Week, data:[0, {y:6441.13, color:#63D654}]}
3: {name:Month, data:[0, 0, {y:145740.4, color:#63D654}]}
4: {name:Qtr, data:[0, 0, 0, {y:0, color:#63D654}]}
5: {name:Year, data:[0, 0, 0, 0, {y:0, color:#63D654}]}
```

I understand that the spacing is caused by the 0 values, but I can't do it any other way.

How do I remove the spacing caused by the 0 value bars?

Or how do I achieve the same grouping I want a different way (which won't require 0 value bars to position them in the right group)?

---

Here is a JS Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfo0ay0q/

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle demo with it? Why do you need 5xseries, not just using one series with all points? Also, try `grouping: false` option - should help.

Comment: Why you use each point as separated serie? Better is using two series

Comment: @SebastianBochan Can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: Its unclear why you use 4 series and each of them, increase amount of 0. Better is using: http://jsfiddle.net/dfo0ay0q/1/